# Expand $X(t) = e^{W(t)}$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let's take $X(t) = e^{W(t)}$ where $W$ is a Wienner process

I want to prove that $dX(t) = \frac12X(t)dt + X(t)dW(t), \;\;\;X(0) = 1$

**My work so far**

Idea of proof is very simple: I want to show that $X$ is an Ito process i.e. is in format of:

$$X(t) = X(0) + \int_0^t\mu(s)ds + \int_0^t\sigma(s)dW(s)$$

because then we know that $$dX(t)=\mu(t)dt + \sigma(t)dW(t)$$

It's easy to see that the wanted equation will be satisfied when I choose $\mu(s) = \frac12 X(s)$, $\sigma(s) = X(s)$.

So there is only one thing left - prove that with such $\mu$ and $\sigma$ specified $X$ is an Ito process, so

$$X(t) = X(0) + \int_0^t\mu(s)ds + \int_0^t\sigma(s)dW(s)$$

$$X(t) = 1 + \int_0^t \frac12 X(s) ds + \int_0^t X(s) dW(s)$$

$$X(t) = 1 + \frac12 \int_0^t e^{W(s)} ds + \int_0^t e^{W(s)} dW(s)$$

It's very easy to calculate that:

$$\frac12 \int_0^t e^{W(s)} ds = \frac12 e^{W(t)} - \frac12$$

But I have no idea how can we calculate

$$\int_0^t e^{W(s)}dW(s)$$

I tried substitution $u = W(s)$ but then what exactly is $\frac{dW(s)}{ds}$ ?

Could you please give me a hand with calculating so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^t e^{W(s)}dW(s)=\int_0^t e^{W(s)}\frac{dW(s)}{ds}ds$$
making the substitution $u=W(s)$ gives:
$$\int_{W(0)}^{W(t)} e^udu=e^{W(t)}-e^{W(0)}$$
I am not sure if this is what you were looking for so let me know

---

If we work backwards from the result you are trying to prove:
$$dX(t)=\frac12X(t)dt+X(t)dW(t)$$
we are able to rewrite this as:
$$\frac{dX(t)}{X(t)}=\frac12dt+dW(t)$$
now integrate both sides and we get:
$$\ln X(t)=\frac t2+W(t)+C\tag{1}$$
which seems like a contradiction as in your definition we have:
$$X(t)=e^{W(t)}\Rightarrow \ln X(t)=W(t)$$

Comment: Well yeah... That was the integral I wasn't sure how to calculate.. however it doesn't prove what I wanted to prove. Do you have idea how my thesis can be showed ?

Comment: I will add to my answer